# why does current tab pause every time when I switch tabs in browser?

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, requestanimationframe

I loaded navMesh and animal using **three.js**. Animal is moving on map. But when I changed the tab animal moving pause and if again open that tab animal moving again from pause point. How to play continue animation either tab changed or background of tab.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sandipnd31/y5xxwj9c/14/)

```
function animate() {
            var currTime = window.performance.now();
            var delta = (currTime - lastFrameTime) / 1000;
            var dTime = Math.min(delta, maxFrameTime);
            elapsedTime += delta;
            lastFrameTime = currTime;

            tick(dTime);

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a feature of `setAnimationFrame` at work. Browsers limit the processing on inactive tabs to save power consumption and CPU cycles. For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5927432/7316502

It doesn't make sense to play an animation that people can't see. However, it might make sense to update the position of the creature in the background and display its current position when the user returns to the tab, given its target point and velocity.

If I understand correctly, the desired outcome is to click a point, have the monster start moving, and then when you tab away and tab back, it's as though the monster has moved the same amount as if you were watching.

You could use the Page Visibility API to help do this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

On a `visibilityChange`, you can check to see if `window.hidden===true`. If so, pause the simulation and await another `visibilityChange` event for which `window.hidden===false`.

When focus returns to the tab, calculate the time difference between the current time and the time the window became hidden. Fast-forward your rendering to this time point. Then continue displaying animation.

### Here is an example of what this might look like.

I placed this in your `init()` function.

```
function handleVisibilityChange() {
    if (document.hidden) {
        windowHidden=true;
        hideTime=window.performance.now();
    } else  {
        windowHidden=false;
        var timeDiff=(window.performance.now()-hideTime)/1000;
        console.log('Page invisible for ',timeDiff,' seconds, jump ahead.');
        tick(timeDiff);
        render();
    }
}
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
```

Then I placed a check in your `tick` function to check the `windowHidden` flag:

```
if (!level||windowHidden) { return; }
```

### (almost-complete) example: https://jsfiddle.net/thmsdnnr/thk80hsh/2/

Note that this does not quite work the way you'd intend: currently the monster just proceeds on the path toward the *next* node while the window is hidden. This is why when you tab back, the monster is off the path, proceeds back to the last node it was headed toward, and then continues.

Since the monster is following a path with multiple points and different directed segments, you'd need to refactor your `tick` function, or (better choice, I think) write another one entirely, that takes the time interval the window was hidden for and calculates the number of nodes on the path the monster would have passed given its velocity and time, removes those nodes, and renders the monster in the correct position.

Comment: after changing the tab animal moves out of the path or map

Comment: Hi Sandip — this is what I meant by needing to refactor your `tick` function or create a `fastForward` method for the moving creatures. It's implementation-specific, so I left it to you.

Comment: if possible try to help me for it

Answer (score 0):

`requestAnimationFrame` passes the current time to the function it calls, so you can declare `function animate(currTime) {...}` and then remove your own `currTime`. In this example, `delta` will be either the amount of time between frames, or the amount of time that passed between leaving and returning to the current tab.

```
function animate(currTime) {  // <-- currTime is populated by requestAnimationFrame
    var delta = (currTime - lastFrameTime) / 1000;

    // I don't think you need dTime anymore

    elapsedTime += delta;
    lastFrameTime = currTime;

    tick(delta);

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
}
```